# Java threadLocal weakReference

Tags: java

When I tried this piece of code by myself. I got the result that there was a three-line output without GC and one line after GC. I have no idea where the output `weak ref key:java.lang.ThreadLocal@21fe5cee,value:java.lang.ref.SoftReference@4d544ec9` and `weak ref key:java.lang.ThreadLocal@79658094,value:java.lang.ref.SoftReference@168ce1d8` comes from, and didn't find any relative operation in the source code, Could someone help to make an explanation.

By the way, I noticed that the `nextHashCode` in `ThreadLocal` is `AtomicInteger`. Could someone help to figure out why it should be `AtomicInteger` instead of `Integer`?

Thanks a lot!

Java version: jdk1.8

The code:

```
public class ThreadLocalDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(()->test("abc",false));
        t.start();
        t.join();
        System.out.println("--gc after--");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> test("def", true));
        t2.start();
        t2.join();
    }

    private static void test(String s,boolean isGC)  {
        try {
            new ThreadLocal<>().set(s);
            if (isGC) {
                System.gc();
            }
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            Class<? extends Thread> clz = t.getClass();
            Field field = clz.getDeclaredField("threadLocals");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object ThreadLocalMap = field.get(t);
            Class<?> tlmClass = ThreadLocalMap.getClass();
            Field tableField = tlmClass.getDeclaredField("table");
            tableField.setAccessible(true);
            Object[] arr = (Object[]) tableField.get(ThreadLocalMap);
            for (Object o : arr) {
                if (o != null) {
                    Class<?> entryClass = o.getClass();
                    Field valueField = entryClass.getDeclaredField("value");
                    Field referenceField = entryClass.getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("referent");
                    valueField.setAccessible(true);
                    referenceField.setAccessible(true);
                    System.out.println(String.format("weak ref key:%s,value:%s", referenceField.get(o), valueField.get(o)));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
weak ref key:java.lang.ThreadLocal@7e423898,value:abc
weak ref key:java.lang.ThreadLocal@21fe5cee,value:java.lang.ref.SoftReference@4d544ec9
weak ref key:java.lang.ThreadLocal@79658094,value:java.lang.ref.SoftReference@168ce1d8
--gc after--
weak ref key:null,value:def
```

Comment: `nextHashCode` is `AtomicInteger` because `ThreadLocal` instances need to be thread-safe.

Comment: The 2 `SoftReference` instances are likely some internal cached housekeeping data used by the JVM during thread start.